# Optimal way to resize and bind byte[] to image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I have `byte[]` that store some image of unknown size. I need to resize this bitmap into 160 x 160 and bind to Wpf window.

Should i convert `byte[]` to `Bitmap`, resize, make `BitmapSource` from it and then use in wpf?

```
//result of this method binds to wpf
private static BitmapSource SetImage(byte[] dataBytes)
{
        var picture = BitmapHelper.ByteToBitmap(dataBytes);

        var resizedPicture = BitmapHelper.Resize(picture, 160, 160);

        var bitmapSource = BitmapHelper.GetSourceFromBitmap(resizedPicture);

        bitmapSource.Freeze();

        return bitmapSource; 
}
```

//BitmapHelper class:

```
    public static Bitmap ByteToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
            return img;
        }
    }

    internal static Bitmap Resize(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height)
    {
        var newImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
        }

        return newImage;
    }


    internal static BitmapSource GetSourceFromBitmap(Bitmap source)
    {
        Contract.Requires(source != null);

        var ip = source.GetHbitmap();
        BitmapSource bs;
        int result;
        try
        {
            bs = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
                IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            result = NativeMethods.DeleteObject(ip);
        }
        if (result == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("NativeMethods.DeleteObject returns 0 (operation failed)");

        return bs;
    }

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
       [DllImport("gdi32")]
       static internal extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);
    }
```

What is the fastest and common method for that case?

Comment: Did you try doing what you just described? Decoding the bytes into a Bitmap, resize that?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen yes, i did it and it works, but im afraid that i do redundant work in some steps. I will add code.

Comment: You'll have to use some image-resizing algorithm. I'd guess the one used by WPF for rendering an image to a given size is highly optimized and you can't do better. So just use vanilla WPF to render your image.

Comment: You seem to have a mix of WinForms (`Bitmap`, `Graphics`), WPF (`BitmapSource`) and interop here. For loading and resizing a bitmap image represented by a byte array you can do that solely in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the `DecodePixelWidth` and / or `DecodePixelHeight` properties of the `BitmapImage`class (which inherits from `ImageSource`).

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
BitmapSource GetImage(byte[] dataBytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes))
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();

        // This is important: the image should be loaded on setting the StreamSource property, afterwards the stream will be closed
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.DecodePixelWidth = 160;

       // Set this to 160 to get exactly 160x160 image
       // Comment it out to retain original aspect ratio having the image width 160 and auto calculated image height
       bi.DecodePixelHeight = 160;

       bi.StreamSource = stream;
       bi.EndInit();
       return bi;
    }
}
```